# How to draw the figure inscribed in a circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In a Geometry problem appears the figure inscribed in a circle, having outline consisting of $8$ ~semicircles, see figure on the left. The radius of each semicircle is $1$.

[image]

By doing some calculations, it's easy to realize that the radius of the circle is `$\sqrt{10}$`

For the solution of the problem, it is interesting to observe the figure on the right.

```
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (1,1) circle [radius=3.16];

\draw (0.5,0) arc(0:-180:1);

\draw (1.5,0) arc(0:180:1);

\draw (0,1.5) arc(-90:-270:1); 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
```

Comment: John Kormylo, the radius is $\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: Assuming the tangent occurs at 60 degrees, (2+\sqrt(3)/2)^2+1.5^2 is not 10.  A test draw seems to fit this.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can form a right triangle, inscribed in the circle, whose catetos measure 2 and 6 respectively. Hypotenuse is the diameter of the circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And a version in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), relying on the fact that the tangent point on the small circle must be the same `point` on the circumcircle, and using some [nice colours](https://ctan.org/pkg/metapost-colorbrewer).

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

input colorbrewer-cmyk

beginfig(1);

    path base, edge, propeller, circumcircle, square;

    base = halfcircle shifted 1/2 right;
    edge = (base & reverse base rotated 180) shifted up scaled 89;
    propeller = for i=0 upto 3: edge rotated 90i .. endfor cycle;
    circumcircle = fullcircle scaled 2 abs(point 1/45 angle 
                    1/2[point 0 of edge, point 4 of edge] of edge);
    square = for i=0 upto 3: point 9i of propeller -- endfor cycle;

    picture P[];
    P1 = image(
        fill circumcircle withcolor Blues 8 5;
        fill propeller withcolor Blues 8 4;
        draw propeller;
    );
    P2 = image(
        fill square withcolor Blues 8 5;
        fill propeller withcolor Blues 8 4;
        clip currentpicture to square;
    );
    P3 = image(
        fill propeller withcolor Blues 8 2;
        draw P2;
        draw propeller;
    );
    draw P1;
    draw P3 shifted 300 right;

endfig;
end.
```

Answer (score 10):

Not an answer, but should settle the issue of the radius.

[image: derivation]

Comment: John Kormylo - I recognize I made a mistake. In fact, the radius can't be $sqrt{10}$. It was really nice to see you!

Comment: Very kind John...I have removed my question on the rocket. Always thank you.

Answer (score 9):

With the radius `r=1+sqrt(5)` (easy to get!).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\cc{(2,0) arc(270:90:1) arc(0:180:1) arc(0:-180:1) arc(90:270:1) arc(90:-90:1) arc(180:360:1) arc(180:0:1) arc(-90:90:1)--cycle;}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1+sqrt(5)}
\fill[teal] (0,0) circle(\r);
\draw[fill=white] \cc;
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace*{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[green!50] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
\begin{scope}
\clip (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
\fill[purple!50] \cc;
\end{scope}
\draw \cc;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Update.** Now I realise that using `fit` library is not suitable for this situation. In fact, [smallest-circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem) is more complicated than direct calculating the above radius.

Another way without calculation is using library `through` after finding out the tangent point as follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0)--(1,2)--([turn]0:1) coordinate (M);
\node[circle through=(M),draw,fill=cyan] at (0,0) {};
\draw[fill=white] (2,0) arc(270:90:1) arc(0:180:1) arc(0:-180:1) arc(90:270:1) arc(90:-90:1) arc(180:360:1) arc(180:0:1) arc(-90:90:1)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is it reasonable that the library `through` is just for `circle through`?!

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0)--(1,2)--([turn]0:1) coordinate (M);
\draw[fill=violet!50] (0,0) 
let \p1=(M) in circle({veclen(\x1,\y1)});
\draw[fill=white] (2,0) arc(270:90:1) arc(0:180:1) arc(0:-180:1) arc(90:270:1) arc(90:-90:1) arc(180:360:1) arc(180:0:1) arc(-90:90:1)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You seem not to use `fit`, do you?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat ah, yes! something like this `\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{tikzpicture}[draw,circle,inner sep=0,outer sep=0]
\path[nodes={minimum size=2cm}] 
(1,2)   node (A) {}
(-2,1)  node (B) {}
(-1,-2) node (C) {}
(2,-1)  node (D) {};
\node[fill=teal,fit=(A) (B) (C) (D)] {};
\draw[fill=white] \cc;
\end{tikzpicture}
` I will update later!

Comment: I added some comment. `fit` library is not suitable here!

Comment: I added another way using `through` library, and without calculation.

Comment: @BlackMild Good idea.I don't have `turn` with `tkz-euclide` but possible with the same idea `\tkzDefPointWith[colinear normed=at X,K=1](O,X) \tkzGetPoint{F}`

Comment: Is it reasonable that the library `through` is just for `circle through`?

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to know the radius of the big circle

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,4/0/B,2/2/O,3/4/X,4/1/Y,1/0/Z,
              0/3/W,3/0/R,4/3/S,1/4/T,0/1/U}
\tkzDefSquare(A,B)\tkzGetPoints{C}{D}
\tkzInterLC(O,X)(X,C) \tkzGetSecondPoint{F}
% or \tkzDefPointWith[colinear normed=at X,K=1](O,X) \tkzGetPoint{F}
\begin{scope}
  \tkzFillCircle[fill=MidnightBlue](O,F)
  \tkzFillPolygon[purple!40](A,...,D)
  \tkzClipPolygon(A,...,D)
  \foreach \c/\t in {S/C,R/B,U/A,T/D}
  {\tkzFillCircle[MidnightBlue](\c,\t)}
\end{scope}
\foreach \c/\t in {X/C,Y/B,Z/A,W/D}
{\tkzFillCircle[purple!40](\c,\t)}
  \foreach \c/\t in {S/C,R/B,U/A,T/D}
  {\tkzFillCircle[MidnightBlue](\c,\t)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

I think The radius of big circle is \sqrt{5}+1. Here XY=4(two small circle diameter= 2*(1+1)) YZ=2. so XZ=\sqrt{4^2+2^2}=\sqrt{20}, so radius of big circle would be (\sqrt{20}+2)/2=\sqrt{5}+1.
I used @Schrödinger's cat code but used radius=\sqrt{5}+1. and here is the figure.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I agree with John Kormylo, i.e. I also do not get a radius of `sqrt(10)`, but maybe I do not understand the construction. The `sqrt(5)+1` is from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/530537/194703).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[arcs/.style={insert path={foreach \X [count=\Y] in {180,90,0,-90} 
   {arc[start angle=\X,end angle=\X+180,radius=1]
   arc[start angle=\X,end angle=\X-180,radius=1] coordinate (#1\Y)}}}]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=arcs]
  \draw[fill=blue!60,even odd rule] (0,0) [arcs]
  (arcs.center) circle[radius={sqrt(5)+1}];  
 \end{scope} 
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=arcs2,xshift=7.5cm]
  \draw (0,0) [arcs=p] (p1) rectangle (p3);  
  \clip[postaction={fill=purple}](p1) rectangle (p3);  
  \draw[fill=green!50,even odd rule] (0,0) 
  [arcs=p] (p1) rectangle (p3);
 \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You beat me by seconds.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Sorry to hear that!

Comment: Thank you. But I keep thinking that the measure of the radius of the circle is $sqrt{10}$. I can't put here the figure that makes clear the value of the radius

Comment: @BeneditoFreire All I know is that if I uses `sqrt(10)` above the circle is too small. I think John Kormylo is right.